# How to insert array value to database

Tags: php

I want to know how to insert 'peter', 'paul', 'mary' permutated value to phpmyadmin database.
My database (id,name1,name2,name3) id is auto-increment.

```
    <?php
    function pc_permute($items, $perms = array()) {
        if (empty($items)) { 
            echo join(' ', $perms) . "<br />";
       } else {
            for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}

$arr = array('peter', 'paul', 'mary');

pc_permute($arr);

?>


1 peter paul mary
2 peter mary paul
3 paul peter mary
4 paul mary peter
5 mary peter paul
6 mary paul peter
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'm use mysql